# Header background video resizes if header height: 100vh

Tags: html, css, video

I am having a problem with playing video in a background of a header. I have set header height to 100vh (because i want it to take full height of viewport). And it does! But if you actually resize your browser window, the video wont be 100% of header, it just gets smaller and smaller.
This is video css

````
```
video#bgvid { 
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    z-index: -100;
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    background: url(placeholder.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: cover; 
}
```
````

Answer (score 1):

This true..
I using vidBg.
He will see this work

https://github.com/blakewilson/vidbg

Comment: I will try it out. Thanks.

Comment: I have tried it out and it still is the same problem. When i resize, it doesnt autofit.

Comment: and yes iv put resize: true

Comment: is there any problem?

Comment: all is fine now. ty